# Книги, пособия по SQL; Oracle, MYSql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, книги, oracle

Посоветуйте пожалуйста хорошие, качественные книги по SQL; Oracle, MYSQL + Теория Баз данных. Интересуют как хорошие справочные пособия,учебники, так и сборники задач. Скачал определенные книги, но поскольку сейчас доступно очень большое количество учебников,разобраться сходу в том какой стоит прочтения, а в котором информация не полная, разрозненная - довольно трудно. Поэтому прошу вашего совета, как у людей знающих и уже прошедший этот этап. Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

SQL

[Учебник](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/content.html)

[Сборник задач](http://sql-ex.com)

Answer (score 2):

Берёте и читаете теорию БД + (при желании) реляционную алгебру.

Прогуглите Мартин Грубер "Понимание sql" - там общие принципы объясняются. Вполне норм книга.

Answer (score 0):

Учебник по SQL это не интересно. SQL очень простой язык, можно брать любой учебник. ИМХО лучшие книги по базам, это те, который про производительность. Для производительности обязательно нужно хорошо знать архитектуру, поэтому она в таких книгах часто очень хорошо разжёвана.

По Oracle это конечно же [Том Кайт](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6311145/) и [Кэри Миллсап,](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/8254752/)

По MySQL [Петя Зайцев](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6573935/)