# Литература для изучения БД и MySQL

Tags: книги, база-данных, mysql

Добрый день. Планирую заняться изучением баз данных, порекомендуйте литературу для изучения БД и MySQL.

Comment: @RandomGuest, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Учитесь пользоваться поиском )) Ссылки только отсюда:

- [первая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/36455)
- [вторая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/233816)
- [третья](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/201823)
- [четвертая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/339229)

Не помню, есть там или нет, но я бы порекомендовал еще вот [это](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do). На русском только второе издание видел (сам его, а не третье читал), может быть, уже третье издание на русском выпустили.